# Wireless accelerometer with Arduino

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, xbee

I'm planning to build something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RGcYiV4hEE
But with an Arduino replaced with the easyUSB chip. Is there any simple solution for that.

Here there is an ADXL335 accelerometer which has analogue outputs and the data is being sent via an Xbee module. Essentially there is no microcontrollers used explicitly at the transmitter's end. I'm expecting this should be possible by just a correct configuration of the Xbee, reading the data on the analogue pins (say D0 to D2) and just setting the RTS pin to high.

On the receiver though, the Xbee, properly configured, is attached to an Arduino Uno board. Now I'm confused. Shall I try and write a program for the Arduino to read the data from the Xbee using the serial communication and then write it to the USB port on the computer or can I use the Arduino board in reset mode as just a serial to USB convertor and do everything on the computer? I'm expecting the latter should be easier, if possible!

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: explain what you want the function to be, explain what you are already doing and then explain exactly what part you are stuck on. It will really hurt you to expect people to watch a youtube video, that would take me longer then readying your question and writing an answer. We also cannot teach you how to make an entire project, so you need to narrow down to problem space.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I've tried to clarify myself. Please let me know if it still doesn't match the criteria. Cheers

Comment: @Sina - If you think your question is ready for reopening, flag for moderator's attention (`flag` link below your question)

Comment: @SinaSalek, now I can tell your question is really just getting the data from the xbee to the computer. an FTDI chip would do this just fine, but I am no arduino expert to fill you in on what works there.

Comment: @Sina does your computer not have a serial port?

Comment: An Xbee is a AVR that reads pins and send its via radio waves.. On the "tilt mouse" you could just use the smallest arduino, gyro/accelemoter and a 433 transmitter and easily(and cheaply) send your own data. Receive it with a TTL 433 receiver directly to usb serial on your pc. Eliminates using all the xzybeez/arudino server side and saves a $$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to use Arduino board as a Serial to USB converter. You don't even need the ATmega chip for that. Just connect the power and the TX/RX pins of the XBee to the corresponding pins on the Arduino board and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

An arduino isn't necessary for this. Just a serial to usb converter. The easiest plug and play method would be just to buy something like this.

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8687